# Firefox/Opera stops showing Gravatars linked over https

Tags: support, gravatar, security, browsers

This is (e.g.) my profile in Opera 12.16:

[image]

Other gravatars are also affected, but not in SE Chat.

When I copy the image URL, I get

- https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6d52c235ec6dd15f30bab444103e7af2?s=42&d=identicon&r=PG

Chrome retrieves the image, no problem, but Opera says:

[image]

**Edit** In the interest of *meta overflow* [a screenie taken in Chat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8s2KB.png), clearly demonstrating that chat displays the avatars fine, but *not* when oneboxing...

I'm not fully aware of what *online certificate validation (OCSP)* is, but it sounds like something worth investigating?

Comment: Verified in Opera Version 12.15 Build 1748.

Comment: OCSP errors are often because of network glitches (the certificate issuer's OCSP server not responding in time). Opera doesn't retest the same site for 24h, so the glitches may seem a bit more persistent than they actually are (there's a way to bypass that limit, but I don't remember the details right now).

Comment: @Yannis I think it has been at least 2 days now. I'll keep you posted, though

Comment: This is also reproducible in Firefox http://i.stack.imgur.com/PZ7YL.png

Comment: @Braiam can you confirm this is also an issue for e.g. github (if you use gravatar there)? I think it's time to look at gravatar.com (added Firefox to the title)

Comment: yeah, github is dead too

Comment: @JoshC opera isn't the only one.

Comment: @Braiam seems to have been resolved now (on Opera at least)